# Can't get air hose to connect back in to compressor

Tags: compressor

I have a 10gal compressor used to fill up tires mostly.  A friend with Alzheimer's disconnected the hose from the compressor.  I don't believe he changed any fittings but I can't get the hose to connect.  I've sprayed with WD40 and am out of ideas.  Help please.

Comment: Is this a quick-connect fitting? Some may need you to pull the "sleeve" or ring back before they will take the fitting to be inserted. A picture would be most helpful...

Comment: Yes, is there a part that looks like a cylinder, possibly with a hex part?

Comment: Can you provide us with a photo of the fitting? It sounds like a quick disconnect where on the compressor side you have to pull back a sleeve then press the male fitting in the hole and release the sleeve this locks the fitting in place.. if you turn off the compressor and bleed the pressure down it will be easier to get the male in far enough with the sleeve pulled back for it to lock in when the sleeve is released.

Comment: Nitto type fittings have a sleeve that must be drawn back to open the jaws that hold the hose, Jameco type have a button that you may need to press, (or maybe it's stuck)